# vendor bundle path being added to my blog

Tags: heroku, jekyll-extensions

I have no idea where these blog posts are coming from. I am running Jekyll on Heroku and not sure where the /vendor/bundle files are coming from. These are not there when I run the site locally. Site is [m2m.io](http://m2m.io/), then click the blog link. Relevant code fragment:

```html
<li class="thisBlog"><h4><span style="float:left;">18 May 2009 &nbsp; </span> &raquo; <a href="/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/test/source/2009/05/18/empty-tags.html"><div class="brand-color" style="float:left;">Some Tags</div></a></h4></li>

<li class="thisBlog"><h4><span style="float:left;">18 May 2009 &nbsp; </span> &raquo; <a href="/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/test/source/2009/05/18/empty-tag.html"><div class="brand-color" style="float:left;">A Tag</div></a></h4></li>

<li class="thisBlog"><h4><span style="float:left;">12 Mar 2009 &nbsp; </span> &raquo; <a href="/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/test/source/2009/03/12/hash-%231.html"><div class="brand-color" style="float:left;">Hash</div></a></h4></li>

<li class="thisBlog"><h4><span style="float:left;">27 Jan 2009 &nbsp; </span> &raquo; <a href="/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/test/source/2009/01/27/empty-category.html"><div class="brand-color" style="float:left;">Category in YAML</div></a></h4></li>

<li class="thisBlog"><h4><span style="float:left;">27 Jan 2009 &nbsp; </span> &raquo; <a href="/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/test/source/2009/01/27/empty-categories.html"><div class="brand-color" style="float:left;">Category in YAML</div></a></h4></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

add

```
exclude:  [ Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, Procfile, vendor, gems]
```

in your _config.yml